# How to Increase Session Time out in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-config, session

I have one site collection where I need a data from Session Storage. So I enable my Session from web.config. I know it is not recommended Session in Sharepoint, but my client needs it.

So Basically My need is I have two login option one with SharePoint default login which is working perfectly fine. but in second option I am using form based authentication. its also working fine, but the problem is when I logged for the first time then I Set one Session variable. the basis of that variable I am calling one web service outside of SharePoint which is returning with my username.

when I refresh my page after 4-5 hours session is set to null because of a session timeout. Can we set SharePoint Session timeout same as SharePoint default logout time? if yes please suggest something. I already follow this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jesusfer/2015/08/27/sharepoint-2013-authentication-lifetime-settings/), but unfortunately, it is not working for me.

Comment: Hi, you cannot actually stop a workflow or pause it for some duration in the SharePoint. However, if you try this it will stop the workflow for a while and then you’ll be able to to do it correctly:

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that in web.config of our application under sessionstorage section:

```
          <sessionState mode="Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer"
          cookieless="true|false"
          timeout="number of minutes"
          stateConnectionString="tcpip=server:port"
          sqlConnectionString="sql connection string"
          stateNetworkTimeout="number of seconds"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a solution for you (needs to be changed in your web.config):

```
<forms name=”name” 
      loginUrl=”url”—————————- This was configured when you configured FBA
      protection=”All|None|Encryption|Validation”
      timeout=”30″ ————————— This is the default expiration (set it here at your convenience)
      path=”/” 
      requireSSL=”true|false”
      slidingExpiration=”true|false”>
  <credentials passwordFormat=”format”/>
</forms>
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/victorbutuza/2008/08/26/forms-based-authentication-timeout/

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if that can help you, but I use this function to refresh active sessions:

```
    function refreshDigestToken() {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue);
        },
        error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
            console.log(errorMessage);
        }
    });
}
```

That way the token should automatically be used for further actions. I have that function on a timer.